# How to use Spark dataset GroupBy()

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, dataset, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a Hive table with the schema:

```
id             bigint
name           string
updated_dt     bigint
```

There are many records having same id, but different name and updated_dt. For each id, I want to return the record (whole row) with the largest updated_dt.

My current approach is:

After reading data from Hive, I can use case class to convert data to RDD, and then use groupBy() to group by all the records with the same id together, and later picks the one with the largest updated_dt. Something like:

```
 dataRdd.groupBy(_.id).map(x => x._2.toSeq.maxBy(_.updated_dt))
```

However, since I use Spark 2.1, it first convert data to dataset using case class, and then the above approach coverts data to RDD in order to use groupBy(). There may be some overhead converting dataset to RDD. So I was wondering if I can achieve this at the dataset level without converting to RDD?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it using `Dataset`:

```
data.groupBy($"id").agg(max($"updated_dt") as "Max")
```

There is not much overhead if you convert it to `RDD`. If you choose to do using `RDD`, It can be more optimized by using `.reduceByKey()` instead of using `.groupBy()`:

```
dataRdd.keyBy(_.id).reduceByKey((a,b) => if(a.updated_dt > b.updated_dt) a else b).values
```

Comment: Thanks. "data.groupBy($"id").agg(max($"updated_dt") as "Max")" only returns max updated_dt, but I want to return the whole record/row with max updated_dt.

Comment: Its mentioned in the link, posted by @user8371915